# Python Geopandas Unable to Locate Shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, fiona

Environment:

```
Python 3.8.6
Conda 4.8.5
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7
```

Attempting to read in an ESRI shapefile of UK upper tier local authority boundaries to a python environment. Attempted in both command line and PyCharm with identical error.

Setup following document guidance:

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas
```

I have confirmed all dependency packages (fiona, pyproj,  shapely, dumpy, pandas) are installed and imported to environment.

But when running the following:

```
local_auth_shape = gpd.read_file('~/Downloads/Counties_and_Unitary_Authorities__December_2017__Boundaries_GB-shp/Counties_and_Unitary_Authorities__December_2017__Boundaries_GB.shp')
```

I am met with the error:

```
fiona.errors.DriverError: ~/Downloads/Counties_and_Unitary_Authorities__December_2017__Boundaries_GB-shp/Counties_and_Unitary_Authorities__December_2017__Boundaries_GB.shp: No such file or directory
```

The path is correct and I have triple checked it. The geo database folder has also downloaded without error.

I have attempted using pip install also with the same error.

Comment: I had the same error once with geopandas 2.0.1 It was due to the geodataframe being empty, I added another check opening the shapefile in fiona and checking if it is not empty then reading it with geopandas

Comment: Why would the data frame be empty? I've tried it with multiple geodatabases and boundary files and keep getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using  another path ? an absolute path starting from root

Comment: Your path is incorrect. It should look like `/Users/martin/Downloads/file.shp` not with `~`.

Comment: That fixed it. Why was this required when other functions such as read_csv can work fine with the tilde?

Comment: The `read_csv` function is from the pandas package, and indeed supports this. I opened https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1664 about potentially supporting this in geopandas as well

Comment: being specific with the path really saves a lot of potential problems